# Notified by Chat Messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, email-notification

I'd recommend adding notifications for when users comment back/write back in a chat. I tend to close the link or end up doing other things making me totally forget about the current Chat I'm having with someone about a  question. It would be nice if we could be notified when user replies.

Otherwise, if we don't want to be notified we can just leave the chat.

Comment: But if someone @replies you do get notified? As shown in this screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CyfFq.png

Comment: You do get notified... just takes 15 minutes.

Comment: I have never been notified. Only when I am invited.

Comment: Yes, @ShadowWizard definitely a duplicate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lukesIvi cheers, you can close this by clicking the "I agree" button.

Comment: Hey thanks. Didn't see that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If a user @replies to you, you do get notified.

It's just partly cached, and the notification delivery to your global inbox can be delayed by ~ 30 mins, though you get a noty in the *chat* inbox immediately, as for the notifications when you're in the room.

There's how it looks in your global inbox (the one which is the "message box" in the top bar).

> [image]

Comment: It's always been 15 minutes for me.

Comment: I don't get notified. Ever....

Comment: @Catija Hm, probably I'm wrong.

Comment: @lukesIvi Do you get people addressing the messages to you using the @? Because if they're just chatting, you're not going to get notified. If you have your sound on, and you have the pings activated, you'll hear a ping notification every time someone directs a message at you, as well. That happens instantly. If you leave the chat room or ignore it, only then do you get the inbox notifications.

Comment: The user usually just types away and doesn't @ me. I'm usually having 1-1 conversations so it's pointless to @ all the time. Just a drag to have to @ someone every time, especially for a 1-1. In a group chat it's more understandable.